# .ZIP not recognised if name changed on download

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, zip, unzip

I scripted a download and unzip for .zip files using Python 3.3. This works with no problem if the name of the .zip remains unchanged. If I try and change the name of the .zip on download then the `zipfile.is_zipfile()` won't recognise the file as a .zip file [though it still unzips in WinRAR].

I change the name by passing the `shutil.copyfileobj()` a different fdst name (not whole path).

The download code used is:

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import os, os.path



def mjd_downloader(url, destdir, destfilename=None):

    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    #if no filename passed by destfilename, retrieve filename from ulr
    if destfilename is None:
        #need to isolate the file name from the url & download to it
        filename = os.path.split(url)[1]

    else:
        #use given filename
        filename = destfilename


    #'Download': write the content of the downloaded file to the new file

    shutil.copyfileobj(response, open(os.path.join(destdir,filename), 'wb'))
```

The unzip code used is:

```
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os, os.path
import shutil

def mjd_unzipper(zippathname, outfilebasename=None):
    #outfilebasename is a name passed to the function if a new name for 
    #the content is requried   
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(zippathname) is True:
        zfileinst = ZipFile(zippathname, 'r')
        zfilepath = os.path.split(zippathname)[0]
        zlen = len(zfileinst.namelist())
        print("File path: ", zfilepath)

        if outfilebasename is not None:
            for filename in zfileinst.namelist():
                memtype = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
                outfilename = os.path.join(outfilebasename + memtype)
                print("Extracting: ", filename, " - to: ", outfilename)
                #curzfile = zfileinst.read(filename)
                curzfile = zfileinst.open(filename)
                shutil.copyfileobj(curzfile, open(
                    os.path.join(zfilepath, outfilename), 'wb'))
        else:
            for i in range(zlen):
                extractfile = zfileinst.namelist()[i]
                memtype = os.path.splitext(extractfile)[1]
                zfileinst.extract(extractfile, path = zfilepath)

        zipfile.ZipFile.close(zfileinst)
    else:
        print("Is not a zipfile")
        pass
```

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: You have a different problem than the extension. The `zipfile.is_zipfile()` method tests the *data* contained in the file, not the filename. I suspect there is some additional data at the start or end of the file, which can throw off `zipfile.is_zipfile()` but is ignored by most zip tools.

Comment: Yeah, I'd find the files on the file system and actually compare the binary content -- diff should work. They're probably different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that your file was never closed:  in line 24 of your download script, you opened your destination file for writing binary data.  It is only when you call `close()` on that same file that the data are pushed from memory to the file (there is also method to call without closing the file, but I can't remember it right now).

In general, it is best to open file objects with the `with` statement:

```
with open(os.path.join(destdir,filename), 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, f)
```

When the `with` statement is used with file objects, it automatically closes them at the end of the block, if you ever `break` out of the block, or if the block is left for any other reason (perhaps an unhandled exception that causes the interpreter to exit).

If you can't use the `with` statement (I think some older Python versions don't support its use with file objects) you can just call close() on the object after you're done:

```
f = open(os.path.join(destdir,filename), 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(response, f)
f.close()
```

I hope this is the reason, because then it would be a simple fix!